# How to enlarge a GradientDrawable programmatically?

Tags: android, shapes

I got a rectangle that very close textview, code and image as following below...

```
private Drawable getShape(int iColor) {
    final int STROKE_WIDTH = 5;
    final float CORNER_RADIUS = 15.0f;

    GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable();
    gd.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    gd.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    gd.setStroke(STROKE_WIDTH, iColor);
    gd.setCornerRadius(CORNER_RADIUS);

    return gd;
}
```

[image]

How do I enlarge the stroke make it to look good?

The textview set to "wrap_content" and set background with the shape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override `getIntrinsicWidth` and `getIntrinsicHeight` methods.

```
 GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(){
            @Override
            public int getIntrinsicWidth() {
                return super.getIntrinsicWidth();
            }

            @Override
            public int getIntrinsicHeight() {
                return super.getIntrinsicHeight();
            }
        };
```